# format numbers before sort in DataTables API

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a column in DataTables which holds some amounts and they are formatted like 1,200.00 and I want to get the max amount on the column. In order to do that I use the below code which I got a problem with at the moment if I have 22.50, 250.00, and 1,200.00 in the column it suppose to give me 1,200.00 as the max amount but it will bring back 250.00 as the biggest.

```
var maxPrice = table
        .column(2)
        .data()
        .sort(function(a,b){
            return a - b 
        })
        .reverse()[0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use datatable api, the `toArray()` method.

Then use JS or jquery to parse the numbers and sort them.

Also use `extractContent()` function to get text instead of html.

```
        /**
        * Get Max Price
        */
        function extractContent(s) {
          var span = document.createElement('span');
          span.innerHTML = s;
          return span.textContent || span.innerText;
        };
        
        var PriceArray = [];
        $( table.column(2).data().toArray() ).each(function( index ) {
            PriceArray.push(extractContent(this).replace(',',''));
        });
        var maxPrice = PriceArray.sort(function(a,b){return a-b}).reverse()[0];
        console.log(maxPrice);
```